# Creating image map - an easy way?

Tags: html, image, imagemap

I need to create some relatively complex image maps ([like this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)) but fear doing them by hand. Is there a tool I can use to create complex maps easily? (Idealy a Windows or Mac app, but web apps also welcome)

Comment: i don't suppose you found something for this, did you?

Comment: I actually ended up doing it by hand ... there don't seem to be any decent tools to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS.

Just make a `<div>` relatively positioned and have a background image.

Then, place a bunch of absolutely positioned, block-level `<a>` tags with certain widths and heights within the div. You can use Firebug to alter the anchor tags' left and right properties until the anchor tags cover their appropriate positions.

Answer (score 1):

Fireworks can create and export image maps very well.
Don't forget to add Matt Stow's Responsive Imagemaps Plugin from http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: well, the URL of the link to the plugin is speaking, but ok best practice